# Restrict some registered users from log in in a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-5

Working on a `laravel 5` app which uses the on board `Authentication system`. Users can register and log in. There is a feature to disable some users. And consequence will be the disabled users will not be able to log in untill they are being enabled.

I have a field `active` in `users` table.

I went through the LoginController and the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. But didn't get any clue where I can check if user is disabled or not.

Any clue or help?

Edit: The `AuthenticatesUsers` trait used in log in.

P.S. **The following code came with laravel not written by me**

```
trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code you are using to authenticate users

Comment: @GuyS please see the edited question.

Comment: Please look at here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-extra-logic-on-login-condition-in-laravel-52

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $c = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        return array_merge($c, ['active' => true]);
    }
```

For more info please visit https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-extra-logic-on-login-condition-in-laravel-52

Comment: Needs to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request` along this method override. Good solution.

Comment: @MASh please let me know your changes so i can put them here for future OP's... :)